# Unable to Open Database File(Code 14) SQLiteDatabase Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Whenever I am trying to get count second time after updating the cursor it is showing that Unable to open Database File

```
package com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Background extends IntentService
{
SQLiteDatabase db;
public Background() {
    super("");
}
public Background(String name) {
    super(name);
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MEDICAL_ALERT", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from profile;", null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            while (true)

            {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                String time = "";
                int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int am_pm = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                int day_of_week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                time = hour + ":";
                if (min < 10)
                    time += "0";
                time += min;
                if (am_pm == 0)
                    time += " AM";
                else
                    time += " PM";
                c = db.rawQuery("select * from Medicinetime where time='" + time + "';", null);
                if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    do {
                        Cursor temp = db.rawQuery("select * from medicineday where medicineid='" + c.getString(2) + "';", null);
                        if (temp.getString(day_of_week + 1).equals("T")) {
                            Cursor temp2 = db.rawQuery("select * from medicinebasic where id='" + c.getString(2) + "';", null);
                            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Reminder.class);
                            i.putExtra("TYPE", temp2.getString(4));
                            i.putExtra("URGENT", temp2.getString(2));
                            i.putExtra("TIME", c.getString(1));
                            i.putExtra("DOSAGE", temp2.getString(3));
                            i.putExtra("NAME", temp2.getString(1));
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } else
            stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    db.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,
            restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
}
```

This is the Code that is throwing the following Error :

```
07-28 19:32:07.728 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp         E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31307 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp     E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31307: (24)     open(/data/user/0/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp/databases/MEDICAL_ALERT-journal) - 
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 31307 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:31307: (24)     open(/data/user/0/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp/databases/MEDICAL_ALERT-journal) - 
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp E/SQLiteLog: (14) statement aborts at 12: [select * from Medicinetime where time='7:32 PM';] unable to open database file
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp E/SQLiteQuery: exception: unable to open database file (code 14); query: select * from Medicinetime where time='7:32 PM';
07-28 19:32:07.729 14700-14769/com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                                                                                     Process: com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp, PID: 14700
                                                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:843)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
                                                                                         at com.example.soumyadeep.medicinealertapp.Background.onHandleIntent(Background.java:60)
                                                                                         at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any Idea ?

Error thrown at getCount() method :

```
c = db.rawQuery("select * from Medicinetime where time='" + time + "';", null);
            if (c.getCount() > 0)
```

Comment: Why are you not using a SqliteOpenHelper?

Comment: Your error message does say `SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file`... So it appears that's the problem

Comment: have u find any solution for this?